# Not able to make video from images using ffmpeg

Tags: video, ffmpeg

This is my log while making images from ffmpeg:

```
Incompatible pixel format 'yuvj420p' for codec 'mpeg4', auto-selecting format 'yuv420p'
[buffer @ 0x9e4f20] w:532 h:800 pixfmt:yuvj420p
[avsink @ 0x9f6240] auto-inserting filter 'auto-inserted scaler 0' between the filter 'src' and the filter 'out'
[scale @ 0xa86ac0] w:532 h:800 fmt:yuvj420p -> w:532 h:800 fmt:yuv420p flags:0x4
Output #0, mp4, to 'output2.mp4':
  Metadata:
    encoder         : Lavf53.21.1
    Stream #0.0: Video: mpeg4, yuv420p, 532x800 [PAR 1:1 DAR 133:200], q=2-31, 200 kb/s, 32 tbn, 32 tbc
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0.0 -> #0.0
Press ctrl-c to stop encoding
[buffer @ 0x9e4f20] Changing frame properties on the fly is not supported.
    Last message repeated 43 times
frame=    1 fps=  0 q=1.0 Lsize=      58kB time=0.03 bitrate=15312.1kbits/s    
video:58kB audio:0kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead 1.321295%
```

This is the command I ran:

```
ffmpeg -r 32 -qscale 1 -i %05d.morph.jpg output2.mp4
```

The output2.mp4 file barely works, as it shows only one image, and lasts for a meagre one second.

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: Are all the JPEGs the same image resolution?  How many are there (i'm guessing 44)?

Answer (score 0):

The "Changing frame properties on the fly is not supported" message is send because all your JEPG doesn't have the same size (as the 1st 532x800)

To handle that case, to can scale all JPEG input image to a given size:

```
ffmpeg -r 32 -qscale 1 -i %05d.morph.jpg -vf scale=532:800 output2.mp4
```

For more info about resizing and scaling with ffmpeg, consult that [page](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Scaling%20%28resizing%29%20with%20ffmpeg)

Comment: `-qscale` is an output option.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't think this solves the problem and may result in dropped frames.